# TFT HSD - 9190J-D1 connection to Raspberry Pi model B

Tags: gpio, pi-4, spi, connection, lcd

- I have Raspberry Pi 4 Model B
- I want to connect SPI TFT 4" LCD HSD-9190J-D1 using GPIO pins.
- Kindly help me up with proper connections and necessary drivers required for the LCD to work as display for Raspberry Pi.

There appears to be limited resources online, looking for genuine support please.

Comment: please add a link to the HSD-9190J-D1 datasheet to your question ... edit the question ... **do not** add comment

Comment: And you show NO research, just asking for help. So I will vote to close this.

Comment: This may get you started: https://www.elecrow.com/wiki/index.php?title=4_Inch_HD_480x320_TFT_Display_with_Touch_Screen_for_Rapberry_Pi